# Getting `req.params` in multer's diskStorage functions

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer, koa

all:

First time using Koa and multer. I've got the file uploading basics down but I can't seem to manage this particular use case:

I have my `editUser` route set up that takes the `userId` from `ctx.params` in order to identify the user being edited.
Say I want to upload a user avatar picture and I want to store it in `uploads/:userId/`, how would I go about passing this `userId` to multer? I have tried the following and been unsuccessful thus far:

- Getting the `userId` from `multer.diskStorage({ destination: (req) => {})`: `req.params`  doesn't seem to exist as it always returns `undefined`.
- Getting `userId` from `multer.diskStorage({ destination: (req) => {} }`: `req.body` returns an object with the request body but it does not include the `userId` as that is passed through `ctx.params`.
- Running the `editUser` function before multer and adding `userId` to `ctx.file`/`ctx.request.body` in it in hopes that it shows up in `multer.diskStorage`'s `req` param.

This is the code for my `editUser` controller:

```
const editUser = async (ctx, next) => {
  const { id } = ctx.params;

  await next();

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { ...ctx.request.body, image: ctx.file.path },
    {
      new: true,
    }
  ).lean();
  if (user) {
    ctx.status = 200;
    ctx.body = user;
  } else {
    throw ERROR_MESSAGES.USER.NOT_FOUND;
  }
};
```

And here is the code for my `multer.diskStorage()` implementation:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (request, file, callback) => {
    const { id } = request.body; // undefined
    const { id } = request.params; // undefined
    const directory = `public/uploads/${id}/`;

    fs.exists(directory, (exists) => {
      if (!exists) {
        return fs.mkdir(directory, (error) => callback(error, directory));
      }
      callback(null, directory);
    });
  },

  filename: (request, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
```

This is the route that triggers the upload/edit:

```
router.post('/:id', upload.single('image'), editUser);
```

I'm not really sure if this is really the best approach or if there is a much simpler way of doing this. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a way about this? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Had to try a different approach.